# proxy 502 error when changing from http to https

Tags: apache, http, reverse-proxy, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

I'm using Vue with Java Spring and Apache to serve a app. When using http the access was working without problem, but when changing to https a proxy error appeared:

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request

Reason: Error reading from remote server
GET http://5.5.32.5/Login 502 (Proxy Error)
```

The configuration in the Apache backend is done to accept ssl (even though the files and paths are OK, don't know if something else is necessary):

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  SSLEngine on 
  SSLCertificateFile /path/file.crt 
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/file.private.key
</VirtualHost>
```

being 8080 the port where the backend is running. In the vite.config.js file i'm also adding this to accept the https but any changes i made resulted in the same error:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '^/api/': {
        target: 'https://5.5.32.5:8080',
        changeOrigin: true,
    secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace('^/api/', '/api/')
      }
    },
    hmr: {
      protocol: 'ws',
      host: '5.5.32.5',
      port: 5173,
      disableHostCheck: true,
    },
    https: true
  },
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/main.js'),
      name: 'VueLatestTable',
      fileName: 'vue-latest-table',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

been long hours for some days trying to figure this out. anyone has any idea or could leave any comment?